# Will an EC2 T3 Instance Crash if it hits 100%

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've read a lot about how T3 Instances work, but I still don't have a clear understanding exactly how the server will react when it hits 100% CPU.

I understand that if I am running a T3 Instance the pricing varies if my CPU % runs over the baseline, but that's not really my concern.

What I am wondering is if my CPU hits 100% will the server crash and stop serving requests or will I just get charged more until the traffic goes down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have unlimited mode enabled, nothing happens out of the ordinary -- you just pay for the additional CPU credits necessary to sustain your workload and the instance behaves like any other.  Too much of this, and it becomes more cost-effective to use a fixed-CPU instance.

But with unlimited mode disabled, when the credits are nearing depletion, the instance's performance degrades, by design.  Gracefully at first and then more aggressively, the hypervisor begins starving the instance of time on the CPU so that it eventually slows down to the instance type's baseline performance behavior... so 100% utilization is no longer possible.  It doesn't crash, it doesn't stop, but (using somewhat round numbers for illustration) your ~3 GHz CPU begins to behave more and more like a  a ~1.2 GHz CPU (on t3.xlarge) or ~300 MHz CPU (on t3.micro).

The problem, of course, is that your instance was already overloaded, so this makes a bad situation worse from a performance standpoint... but you can monitor your credit balance and see this coming -- the initial slowdown as credit balance is getting down to within a few 10's of 0 is quite smooth.

Comment: T3 Instances are set to unlimited mode by default correct? Our traffic is pretty low, but when we send out notifications to our user base it spikes for a few minutes. Then drops off.

Comment: The initial default is for t3 to launch as unlimited and t2 to launch as standard.  You can change this at the instance level (of course, since it's only a "default") but you can also reset the default values used for new instances per account/region/type.